# Why doesn't my pointer initialize properly with Arduino?

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I am struggling with [initialising my pointer](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Pointer) to an struct in arduino, I am doing this in my constructor

```
basicSensor* sensor = &m_tsensor;
```

My class

```
class A{
  typedef struct basicSensor {
    float temperature;
    float humidity;
    float pressure;
    }m_tsensor;
private:
public:
   struct data {
    m_tsensor* sensor;
    m_tacc* acc;

  } myData;

}
```

The error

```
warning: unused variable 'sensor' [-Wunused-variable]

     basicSensor* sensor = &m_tsensor;

                  ^

exit status 1
expected primary-expression before ';' token
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: adv: Don't use `typedef struct` in `C++` and don't follow a `struct` definition with an identifier (like you do with `m_tsensor`). Then things should simplify a little.

Answer (score 1):

`m_tsensor` is a type; You can't take the address of a type. Maybe you intended to create an object first and then assign the pointer to that objects address?

Comment: then what should I do?

Comment: Remove `typedef`.

Comment: And replace m_tsensor by basicSensor where you declare other variables if this type...

Comment: YEs I think i did so, if I remove `typdef` the compiler complains `    'm_tsensor' does not name a type`

Comment: I do now `basicSensor* sensor = &basicSensor ;` still complaining `error: expected primary-expression before ';' token

     basicSensor* sensor = &basicSensor ;`

Comment: Why do you even you as pointer? I looks like `sensor` should by a regular member.

Comment: because some data will have that sensor and other not

Comment: @ndarkness m_tsensor does not name a type, it's a member variable (after you remove the typedef). You just need keep: basicSensor* = &m_tsensor; in your c-tor.

Comment: @ndarkness It's the declaration of "sensor" member in the "struct data" that need to be "basicSensor*" instead of "m_tsensor*".

Comment: @mgagnon it seems not to work, now the compiler doesn't complain with     `//basicSensor* sensor = &m_tsensor ;//accelerometerSensor* acc = &m_tacc ;` but I cannot assign a value to it with `frame->frameData.sensor->temperature = 104;`

Comment: @ndarkness Probably because m_tsensor member variable is private. You need to either put it public, or use a public function that return a pointer (or a reference) of it.